# Indices of max values in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, octave

Let's say I have the following matrix:

```
 j = 
 1   2   3   4  
 1   2   3   4  
 5   6   7   8  
 5   6   7   8
```

I would like to get back the following matrix:

```
z =  
3 4  
4 4
```

My experience with the max command hasn't yielded a result that resembles z, it appears that the max function turns the argument into a column vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want the *row and column indices* of *all occurrences* of the maximum computed *across all dimensions* (i.e. the maximum is a single value, which possibly appears in several entries). Then:

```
[rows, cols] = find(j==max(j(:)));
result = [rows cols];
```

Comment: I assume it would be j(:) within the max brackets in the example above

Comment: Whoops. Corrected. But you may not want to use `j` as a variable, to avoid shadowing its original value (imaginary unit)